# ASP.NET 5 MVC JSON Response via Web Api, HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

im trying to answer a Get Request in My Web Api with a JSON File in a poll application. When a user of my application uses a token, I want to response a PollParticipation object, which contains a a poll, a list of the options of the poll, a list of my UserPollOptions (The connection between the UserPoll and the Option) and a List with lists of userPollOption with the answers of other participants.

The problem is that I am receiving a HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet("{token}")]
    [Route("pollway/{token}")]
    public PollParticipation Participate(string token)
    {

        PollParticipation myPoll = new PollParticipation();
        if (!_dbContext.UserPollModels.Any(u => u.UserPollToken == token))
        {
            return new PollParticipation();
        }
        UserPollModel userPoll = _dbContext.UserPollModels.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserPollToken == token);
        PollModel thisPoll = _dbContext.PollModels.FirstOrDefault(u => u.PollId == userPoll.PollId);

        myPoll.poll = thisPoll;

        // List of all Options
        List<OptionModel> options = new List<OptionModel>();
        options = _dbContext.OptionModels.Select(x => x).Where(y => y.PollId == thisPoll.PollId).ToList();
        myPoll.options = options;

        //List of all UserPollOptions from my UserPollId
        List<UserPollOptionModel> myUserPollOptionModels = new List<UserPollOptionModel>();
        myUserPollOptionModels =
            _dbContext.UserPollOptionModels.Select(x => x).Where(y => y.UserPollId == userPoll.UserPollId).ToList();
        myPoll.MyUserPollOptions = myUserPollOptionModels;


        //List of all UserPolls, where the user already participated at the survey
        List<UserPollModel> userPolls = new List<UserPollModel>();
        userPolls = _dbContext.UserPollModels.Select(x => x).Where(y => y.PollId == thisPoll.PollId).Where(z => z.Participation != false).ToList();

        //Delete my own UserPollId out of the List
        foreach (var userPollModel in userPolls)
        {
            if (userPollModel.UserPollId == userPoll.UserPollId)
            {
                userPolls.Remove(userPollModel);
            }
        }

        //Make a list of UserPollOptions for each UserPollRelation that participated
        List<List<UserPollOptionModel>> otherUserPollOptionModels = new List<List<UserPollOptionModel>>();
        foreach (var userPollModel in userPolls)
        {
            List<UserPollOptionModel> tempUserPollOptionModels =
                _dbContext.UserPollOptionModels.Select(x => x)
                    .Where(y => y.UserPollId == userPollModel.UserPollId)
                    .ToList();
            otherUserPollOptionModels.Add(tempUserPollOptionModels);
        }
        myPoll.OtherUserPollOptions = otherUserPollOptionModels;

       return myPoll;

    }
```

I also tried it using a false link then the application successfull send a PollParticipation (in line 8) where the attributes had the value Null:

```
{
poll: null,
options: null,
MyUserPollOptions: null,
OtherUserPollOptions: null
}
```

I also tried to change the return type to IActionResult or JSON result and tried it with "return new ObjectResult (myPoll)" or "return new JsonResult(myPoll). Another try was to just add only the Poll to the PollParticipation and not the lists. This also did not work.

This is what my PollParticipation class looks like, it is not mapped in the database:

```
public class PollParticipation
{
    public PollModel poll { get; set; }

    public List<OptionModel> options { get; set; } 

    public List<UserPollOptionModel> MyUserPollOptions { get; set; }

    public List<List<UserPollOptionModel>> OtherUserPollOptions { get; set; }


}
```

Can somebody help me? Thank you!

**EDIT + Solution**

The solution is to write [JsonIgnore] above the virtual lists in the OptionModel and userPollOptionModel class. They were referencing them selfes in the building of the json File.

Comment: Glad you figured your issue out! Please create and accept an answer with your solution so the question no longer shows up in the _unanswered_ queue. StackOverflow [wants you to do this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if you found the solution on your own.

Comment: [JsonIgnore] on a class within the class I wanted to serialize did the trick. Thanks!